# ¿Cómo puedo conseguir mayor velocidad en Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, fcm

Necesito enviar más de 500k notificaciones push a un canal de Firebase.

Aunque la cifra es pequeña FCM tarda varios segundos en entregar los mensajes, tiene un retraso mayor a 30 segundos a pesar de tener prioridad alta.

Para mi aplicación es vital entregar todas esas push en menos de 5 segundos pues se trata de avisos de emergencia, ¿Tienen alguna recomendación para acelerar el envío?

Answer (score -1):

Firebase actualmente no garantiza un tiempo de entrega aproximado para las push, eso depende, de la conexion del dispositivo al que le llega, de la conexion y la arquitectura de los servidores para manejar esos datos a cada usuario (a algunos les puede llegar mas rapido que a otros).

Hay muchas preguntas de este tipo en el sitio de SO en ingles y algunos issues abiertos en github

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/83

Muchas veces tiene que ver tambien con la prioridad de como se esten enviando esos mensajes, en la documentacion oficial encontramos lo siguiente

> Configuración de la prioridad de un mensaje En Android, hay dos
>   opciones para asignar una prioridad de entrega a los mensajes
>   descendentes: prioridad normal y alta. La entrega de los mensajes con
>   prioridad normal o alta funciona de la siguiente manera:
>
> **Prioridad normal**. Esta es la prioridad predeterminada para los
>   mensajes de datos. Los mensajes con prioridad normal se entregan de
>   inmediato cuando la app está en primer plano. Cuando el dispositivo
>   está en Descanso o la app está en App Standby, se puede retrasar la
>   entrega para ahorrar batería. Para los mensajes menos urgentes, como
>   las notificaciones de correos electrónicos nuevos, la sincronización
>   de IU o la sincronización de datos de app en segundo plano, selecciona
>   la prioridad de entrega normal.
>
> Cuando recibas un mensaje de prioridad normal en Android que solicite
>   una sincronización de datos en segundo plano para tu app, debes
>   programar un trabajo FJD o un JobIntentService para gestionarlo cuando
>   la red se encuentre disponible.
>
> **Prioridad alta**. FCM intenta entregar los mensajes de alta prioridad de
>   inmediato, lo que permite que el servicio de FCM active un dispositivo
>   inactivo cuando es necesario y ejecute un procesamiento limitado
>   (incluido el acceso de red altamente limitado). En general, los
>   mensajes con prioridad alta generan la interacción de los usuarios con
>   la app. Si FCM detecta un patrón en el que no lo hacen, puede reducir
>   la prioridad de los mensajes.
>
> Como una pequeña porción de la población móvil de Android se encuentra
>   en redes de alta latencia, evita abrir una conexión a tus servidores
>   antes de mostrar una notificación. La devolución de llamadas al
>   servidor antes del final del tiempo de procesamiento permitido puede
>   ser algo arriesgado para los usuarios en redes de alta latencia. En
>   lugar de eso, incluye el contenido de la notificación en el mensaje de
>   FCM y muéstralo de inmediato. Si necesitas sincronizar contenido
>   adicional de la aplicación en Android, puedes programar un trabajo FJD
>   o un JobIntentService para gestionarlo en segundo plano.

Puedes referirte a esta documentacion para leer y entender mas como funciona

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#configuracin-de-la-prioridad-de-un-mensaje

Pero para cerrar, es muy improvable saber con exactitud cuando le va a llegar un mensaje a un determinado usuario, imaginate enviar 500.000 notificaciones y que tengan que llevar todas en 5 o menos segundos, eso va a depender en muchisimos factores como te comentaba arriba, el tiempo que tarda el mensaje en llegar a cada telefono puede diferir.